# jquery timedate picker gets today's date wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the date and time picker [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) where today's date is Sunday the 17th I get Saturday the 17th ,here is my code

```
  $('.dtPickerFrom')
                .datetimepicker(

                        {
                            timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
                            dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
                            showOn : "button",
                            buttonImage : "/resources/images/calender_icon.png",
                            buttonImageOnly : true,
                            minDate : 0
                        });
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you validate this?

Comment: Is it jQueryUI datepicker or the 3rd party plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#basic_examples?

Comment: set the maxDate also and try.

Comment: third party plugin, you can find the link @LiorBar-On

Comment: This actually happened once, any idea why it happened from the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a current date with jQuery [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) using `setDate`.

For example:

`$(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());`

I found [THIS](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-set-current-date-as-default-date-in-jquery-datepicker/) to be pretty helpful

Comment: doesn't the plugin do this by default? if not so how does it display the dates?